# ScrollIntoView is not working for I.E in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, js-scrollintoview

Basically I have a time dropdown, But selected time is not scrolling, on I.E

`scrollIntoView`

```
if (open) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.value &&
      this[this.props.value] &&
      this[this.props.value].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'nearest',
        inline: 'nearest'
      });
  }, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to check your sample code and found that you are trying to using **behavior: 'smooth'** which is not supported in the IE browser.

[image]

I suggest you remove the **behavior: 'smooth'** and again try to test the issue with the IE browser.

References:

1. [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
2. [scrollIntoView](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview)

Comment: Is there any alternate you can provide ?